# Pusher Beams getInitialMessage() null on flutter

Tags: android, flutter, pusher

I'm trying to make deep link, on Android notification click, I receive notification, but method getInitialMessage returns null. I'm using Pusher docs to send notification:

```
Future<String> initialMessage() async {
    final initMessage = 
                  await PusherBeams.instance.getInitialMessage();
    if (initMessage != null) {
    Logger().d('_initialMessage: ${initMessage['open_magic'].toString()}');   } }
```

And I call this method like this:

```
void init(bool isWeb) async {
if (!isWeb) {
  await PusherBeams.instance.start(instanceID);
  await PusherBeams.instance.setDeviceInterests(['debug-chat']);
  await _initialMessage();
}}
```

And my *init()* method, I call in *main* func:

```
main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  MainPusherBeams().init(kIsWeb);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm using last library pusher_beams: ^1.1.1

Comment: I know it's late, but, no, I didn't found the solution. I changed pusher beams on google FCM. But I did it, because of pusher support answered me that this problem has to be. I wait about month or something, but they still didn't fix it, and then I have changed API

Comment: I moved to pushy.me

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and the problem for me was the structure of the data object has to follow the scheme they requested in the docs otherwise it will come `null`.

```
"data": {
   "info": { "my_data": "my_lovely_data" }
}
```

Ex from my debug page:
[image]

Comment: If it's, so it is Super! :) But as I said in my comment up there, it is not actual for me now

Comment: That's great! Let's leave it for the future vistors :)